# javafx listview и checkbox

Tags: javafx, listview, checkbox

Как задать каждому элементу listview, checkbox, и при нажатии на кнопку "Сохранить" проверить выбран ли элемент? Проблема в том, что я не могу заранее создать checkbox, т.к. неизвестно сколько фамилий будет в списке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
   `@FXML
    private void addChoiceFile(ActionEvent event) {
    Node source = (Node) event.getSource();
    Stage primaryStage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter tXTFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("TXT files (*.txt)", "*.txt");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(tXTFilter);
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(tXTFilter);
    fileChooser.setTitle("Выбор файла");
    fileObject = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
    try {
        fileSearch.setText(fileObject.getPath());
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    try {
        listName.clear();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileObject), "utf8"));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        listName.add(line);
        while (line != null) {
            line = reader.readLine();
            if (line != null) {
                listName.add(line);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    infoSurname.setItems(listName);
```

Эту часть кода я пишу сразу же, ниже infoSurname.setItems(listName); И это прекрасно отображает чекбоксы перед каждой фамилией, но в дальнейшем я не могу использовать проверку i-го элемента(выбран или нет).

```
    class CheckBoxListCell extends ListCell<String> {
       @Override
       protected void updateItem(String obj, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(obj, empty);
            if (obj != null && !empty) {
                CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(obj);
                checkBox.selectedProperty();
                setGraphic(checkBox);
            } else {
                setGraphic(null);
            }
        }
    }
    infoSurname.setCellFactory(param -> new  CheckBoxListCell());

}`
```

При нажатии на кнопку "Сохранить", я желаю выполнять проверку на наличие галочки у чекбокса.

if (checkBox.isSelected()), вот эту проверку мне необходимо вставить между for и try.

```
@FXML
private void printFile(ActionEvent event) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listName.size(); i++) {

        try {
```

Помогите пожалуйста, кто чем может =)

Answer (score 0):

Вобщем проблему решил, скину код, может кому пригодится.
Получаю в итоге массив с выбранными людьми:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И делаю проверку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]